# eCommerce add-on for an ASP.Net site (non MVC) and 4.0 based

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

I have been searching here on stackoverflow, Google, and elsewhere but not having very much luck, so I was hoping that someone here might have an idea.

I have an existing Visual Studio 2012 ASP.Net 4.0 non-MVC website.  I just need to add in the ecommerce portion.  The site is not Amazon style by any stretch of the imagination, but there is an area on the site, where users can press a button and add an item to a cart.  There should be an admin side, etc.

The problem that I have is that I have no clue which ecommerce package is best.  There are several packages if you start from their template and then modify via admin panel or otherwise.  I just wish to add on.

The more obvious choices have issues:

nopCommerce: Requires MVC and .Net Framework 4.5.  That lets that out for both reasons.  My web hosting company supports 4.0 and 2.0,  not 4.5.  Also, I have a non-MVC ASP.net application.  I should add that their support system is non-existent.

dotshoppingcart: That had the most promise, but they are moving to MVC and no support.

PHP based is definitely out.

Simply using a button and passing control to another page, which yields a different domain, hence two different products coexisting, is a nice idea, but has issues, such as the shopping cart item, although I guess if I had the db layout, then that could be programmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vevocart.com/

This is one link which I found useful out recently... which is Not MVC based.... it also has many versions ... so you can select whichever suits you ......hope it hepls you.

Comment: I was evaluating VevoCart, still am.  The product on the face of it seems a good fit.  They go out of their way in the docs to say how to create a button.  The company refuses to say how to get a cart icon functionality with the number of items in the cart showing.  Documented db access?  The docs for community version are not accurate and they do not go into necessary details, such as what passwords can and cannot have.  I am still evaluating the product to see if I can use it.

Comment: I figured out how to add a shopping cart line to my header. Sadly, VevoCart support did nothing to help. I had to research the issue. Here it is for posterity. The current shopping cart line is a component, which you can include in your project as an ASP.net control, which can be found at "/Components/CurrentShoppingCart.aspx(.cs)".

Comment: Although VevoCart support is somewhat rude and anything but pleasant to deal with, they were helpful in answering my presales questions.  It appears that VevoCart will do the job.  I am spoiled with DevExpress.  They are g-ds in customer relationship and quality.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off coding this yourself (caveat: own blog post):

[Integrate PayPal Checkout Button with ASP.NET 2.0](http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/27/Integrate-PayPal-Checkout-Button-with-ASPNET-20.aspx)

Comment: I ran into some time ago the PayPal ASP.Net SDK and then forgot about it.  I perused the subject and saw that PayPal no longer supports the platform.  Their pricing and ease of integration does not make it conducive to suffer with the platform.  Authorize.net as a payment gateway is more cost effective and provides more.  I did try to go this route and was not satisfied.  The workaround for the form tag issue is nauseating at best and not practical.  Also, I have a .Net 4.0 site.  If I wanted not nice, I would stick with ShareIt or BMT Micro, both offer better services than PayPal.